# python occupied memory keeps getting accumulated when ran through service and not released to OS (tornado)

Tags: python, python-2.7, tornado

We used windows task manager for monitoring memory consummation. Initially, after running the service, consumed memory is "12.0 MB". When We hit http GET request for "http://localhost:8888/abc" at point 2 (Pointed in above code) Memory goes to 30MB. As code proceeds to point 3 memory consumption is increased till 31MB. After point 3, as per our observation the memory never comes down and it remains at 31 MB. As we invoke HTTP GET request multiple times this memory consumption in increased during each request as 32MB, 33MB and so on and it never comes down. We tried using "del emr_client" using **del** method to delete emr_Client object but nothing seems to be working. In our larger code base this accumulated memory is causing our web server going into unhealthy status and only option we have is the stop and start the service. Same behavior exist for Linux machine too.

We understand that python keeps imported package in memory for faster execution of subsequent calls but any reason the memory is not released after life of an object (ex. emr_client in above example) comes to end after it's scope is complete.

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
from tornado.httpserver import HTTPServer

class BotoContainer:
    def __init__(self):
        import boto3 # 2
        emr_client = boto3.client("emr", **{'region_name': 'us-east-1',
                                        'aws_access_key_id': 'XXXXXXX',
                                        'aws_secret_access_key': 'XXXXXXX',
                                        'aws_session_token': 'XXXXXXX'})
        print emr_client # 3


class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        BotoContainer()


class Application(tornado.web.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        handlers = [
        (r"/abc", MainHandler)
    ]

        tornado.web.Application.__init__(self, handlers)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = HTTPServer(Application())
    app.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Comment: Does the memory size keep growing without limit?

Comment: Every subsequent calls it keeps growing by few MBs and then it never comes down. Eventually it consumes entire memory which brings down the machine